# How can I handle plugin-like dependencies in MSBuild?

Tags: c#, plugins, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have a project which ships with a plugin model. It also ships with a couple of default plugins. I'd like to tell Visual Studio (and MSBuild on the Team Build server) that when building the main application, that it needs to copy "DefaultPlugin.dll" from the "DefaultPluginProject"'s `$(OutDir)` into its own `$(OutDir)Plugins`.

I explicitly do not want to add project references from the main project to the plugin project; this would make it possible for the main project to compile if it depends on a plugin, which is undesirable. The project dependency system's "CopyLocal" only copies directly into `$(OutDir)` in any case, not to `$(OutDir)Plugins`.

Is there some way to retrieve `$(OutDir)` from a ProjectReference item in MSBuild?

For reference, I've tried these two solutions:

- Run a Post-Build-Step which copies the files over. This fails on the build server because the value of `$(OutDir)` is in a completely different place there.
- Set the output directory for the plugin project to be "..\MainProject\x86\Debug\Plugins". This is undesirable because it makes figuring out which project caused which files to be copied where difficult.

Comment: The Post-Build-Step should work as long as you use relative paths. I would recommend using them anyways.

Comment: @Ryan: No, that fails on the build server.

Comment: @Ryan: No, that fails on the build server. On the build server, all the project's output paths get set to some absolute location. You can see this behavior by doing `msbuild YourProject.sln /p:OutputPath=C:\Some\Absolute\Path`